# Cannot read properties of null of addEventListener

Tags: javascript

```
    document.querySelector('#book-form').addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    //Prevent actual submit
    e.preventDefault();
   //Get form values
    const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
    const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
    const pages = document.querySelector('#pages').value;
    const book = new Book(title, author, pages);
    console.log(book)
});
```

I have tried a couple different solutions from stack but even if the error doesn't show up on visual studio it will appear when I hit inspect on my book list webpage which is the application I'm working on.

Comment: What is `document.querySelector('#book-form')` at the time this runs? Does it run before the DOM has loaded?

Comment: Does the id `book-form` exists on your html dom element?

Comment: When referencing objects in the DOM, your javascript should be below the actual elements.

Comment: The book form id does exist in the html yes

Comment: You should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the entire context.